# Solution of 2nd order system of ODEs

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve the following system of ODEs.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2}{dy^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\  
v
\end{bmatrix}
+
\frac{d}{dy}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\  
4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\  
v
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\  
4 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\  
v
\end{bmatrix}
=0
\end{equation}

What is the general solution and how can I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this equation? When I googled it, just the first-order system of ODEs solution is given.

P.S. Numbers may cause problematic solutions. I randomly chose them.

Comment: Write it as a first order equation in the variables $u,v, u',v'$.

Comment: @copper.hat but in that case, won't it end up with different eigenvalues?

Comment: Different to what?

Comment: If I write it in first-order equation form, eigenvalues of the first-order system and the eigenvalues of the second-order system will be different, right?

Comment: I don't know how you define eigenvalues of the second order system so I cannot say. However, both systems are equivalent os there must be some relationship.

Comment: Actually, I discretized a system like this (not this one, mine is a little more complicated), numerically and I found the eigenvalues. Since I don't know the general solution, I couldn't use these eigenvalues to find the solution. In my case, It turns into an eigenvalue problem because of the zero boundary conditions.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question. You asked how to solve the system and one standard way of solving a linear ode is to convert it into a first order system and compute the exponential of the resulting '$A$' matrix. If you are looking for something else then you need to update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally, the 2nd order vector ODE

$$\ddot {\bf x} + {\bf A} \dot {\bf x} + {\bf B} {\bf x} = {\bf 0}$$

can be rewritten as follows

$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \begin{bmatrix} {\bf x} \\ \dot {\bf x} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf O} & {\bf I}\\ -{\bf B} & -{\bf A}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} {\bf x} \\ \dot {\bf x} \end{bmatrix}$$